# processing grammar using spaCY

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, spacy

I'm going to check for grammar in the sentences I give as input. If **spaCy** identifies `PRP` and `MD` and `NN` in a sentence then it will give me a text output

> there is a prp, md and nn in the sentence

The problem is: how can I tell **spaCy** to check for `PRP`, `MD` and `NN` and then give me the desired text output?

This is the code so far which is able to identify grammar of a text input:

```
import spacy

sent=input("insert sentence: \n\n")
nlp=spacy.load('en')
doc=nlp(sent)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.tag_, token.dep_)
```

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: as I wrote I'm trying to get as output the text string "there is a prp, md and nn in the sentence" only when spaCy actually detects the presence of a PRP, MD and NN in the input (eg: "I will go to the mall" it contains all of them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
In [34]: chk_set = set(['PRP','MD','NN'])

In [35]: chk_set.issubset(t.tag_ for t in nlp("I will go to the mall"))
Out[35]: True

In [36]: chk_set.issubset(t.tag_ for t in nlp("I will go"))
Out[36]: False
```

**UPDATE:**

> how can I read the word marked as NN and print it out?

```
In [53]: [t.text for t in nlp("I will go to the mall") if t.tag_ in ['NN']]
Out[53]: ['mall']
```

Comment: YES. Thank you sir! it seems to work fine. One last thing, what if, for example, I just want to print out the NN associated word contained in the sentence "I will go to the mall" which in this case is " I ". how can I read the word marked as NN and print it out as output?